# Find if values across multiple columns are present within a string

Tags: r, string, detect

I am trying to determine whether drug names which are spread across multiple columns, are present within a string. I am using str_detect, and eventually need to refer to column indices as I don't know how many columns I need to use to search.

Example data:

```
string.to.search<-c("abc","bc","cd","e","f")
Drug1<-c("b","c","e","f",NA)
Drug2<-c("c","d",NA,NA,NA)
Drug3<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(string.to.search, Drug1, Drug2, Drug3))
```

I can do this easily enough when referring to the columns I wish to use as search terms (Drug1 to Drug3 in this instance), and achieve the desired result:

```
df.new<-df%>%
  mutate(Found = str_detect(string.to.search, paste(Drug1, Drug2, Drug3, sep="|")))
```

| String.to.search | Drug1 | Drug2 | Drug3 | Found |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a b c | b | c |  | TRUE |
| b c | c | d |  | TRUE |
| c d | e |  |  | FALSE |
| e | f |  |  | FALSE |
| f |  |  |  | FALSE |

I have found it is possible to use a column index, but can only make this work for a single column:

```
df.new2<-df%>%
  mutate(Found = str_detect(string.to.search, .[[2]]))
```

| String.to.search | Drug1 | Drug2 | Drug3 | Found |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a b c | b | c |  | TRUE |
| b c | c | d |  | TRUE |
| c d | e |  |  | FALSE |
| e | f |  |  | FALSE |
| f |  |  |  |  |

I can't figure out how to make this work across multiple column indices so that I can go from the second to the last column (I might have 1 drug or I might have 10 in future). When I try this I get the following error:

```
df.new3<-df%>%
  mutate(Found = str_detect(string.to.search, .[[2:ncol(df)]]))
```

*Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Found`.
i `Found = str_detect(string.to.search, .[[2:ncol(df)]])`.
x recursive indexing failed at level 2*

When I just look at what is returned by `df[2:ncol(df)]`, only the three Drug columns are returned as expected, so I feel like I must be using the correct indices.

Any help greatly appreciated.

- ps I have tried similar code with grepl and get the same results, but I am happy to use that instead of str_detect if that's more logical.

Comment: If all of your drugs are not always single letters, then I suggest that your sample data may be over-simplified: sub-string matches may give false-positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `string.to.search` is always space-delimited (or something easily split), then we can use `%in%` instead of string-matches; the latter can provide false-positives if you have sub-string matches.

```r
df <- structure(list(string.to.search = c("a b c", "b c", "c d", "e", "f"), Drug1 = c("b", "c", "e", "f", NA), Drug2 = c("c", "d", NA, NA, NA), Drug3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
df
#   string.to.search Drug1 Drug2 Drug3
# 1            a b c     b     c  <NA>
# 2              b c     c     d  <NA>
# 3              c d     e  <NA>  <NA>
# 4                e     f  <NA>  <NA>
# 5                f  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>

df %>%
  mutate(
    Found = Reduce(`|`,
      lapply(subset(., select=Drug1:Drug3),
             function(z) mapply(`%in%`, z, strsplit(string.to.search, " +"))))
  )
#   string.to.search Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 Found
# 1            a b c     b     c  <NA>  TRUE
# 2              b c     c     d  <NA>  TRUE
# 3              c d     e  <NA>  <NA> FALSE
# 4                e     f  <NA>  <NA> FALSE
# 5                f  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, my string to search is indeed space delimited, I should have constructed my example better. Your solution does work, but I'm struggling to make it work for an unknown number of drugs. Replacing `select=Drug1:Drug3` with `select=[2:ncol(df)]` results in the error that R found an unexpected "[", so I think I am referring to the columns incorrectly.

Is there any way to refer to the columns by index? I always expect it to run from column 2, but could have from 1 to X number of drugs.

Comment: I managed to work it out in fact using: `dd<-names(df[2:ncol(df)])` and `select=dd`

Thanks very much @r2evans!

Comment: Your second solution works, but `[2:ncol(df)]` is more python-y than R-y. Remove the `[` brackets, just `select=2:ncol(df)` should work. However, since you're looking for all except the first, you can also do `select=-1` or `select=-string.to.search`. Glad it helped!

Comment: Frankly, the reason I chose `subset(.)` was because I did not assume the number of columns, and its ability (same with `dplyr::select`) to allow ranges of columns is very nice. In place of `subset(..)`, you could also use `select(., -string.to.search)`, same effect. But since you know it's the first, you can replace the whole ``subset(...)` with just `.[,-1]`, as in `lapply(.[,-1], function(z)...)`. (Just code-golf; I prefer the `select=-string.to.search` personally, as it does not rely on column position and is more declarative, easier to maintain.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, the different options are really helpful and I appreciate that you put thought into not relying on column position. I have now been able to implement this in my somewhat more complicated data set and it works exactly how I'd hoped! I was getting quite frustrated so it's nice to have an elegant way of doing this as opposed to me creating a horrible work-around.